# Data Scrubbing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

The requirement is to scrub the data. I have loaded data from a flat file into a SQL Server table in some columns there are some values like -111, -11, -11 i.e starting with negative values and there are some empty spaces how can I replace all of these values with a NULL in all the tables of my database?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow.  In order to help answer your questions, we like to see code snippets, table structures, example inputs/outputs, error messages, and any information relevant to your specific question.

Comment: If you don't know about SSIS, then why did you include it as a tag?

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL Server 2012, use the `TRY_CONVERT` function to cast what can be cast and NULL the rest.

```
TRY_CONVERT(DataType, FieldName)
```

If trying to clean the data, you can use `CHARINDEX` to find invalid values, in your example it'd be where criteria, or a CASE statement using `CHARINDEX`:

```
Fieldname = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',Fieldname) > 0 THEN NULL ELSE Fieldname END
```

As per your request:

```
DECLARE @Iterator varchar(55),@strSQL VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
--Select stuff to iterate over
SELECT DISTINCT t.name
FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
 sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN
 sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id

OPEN xyz 

FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--Do stuff
SET @strSQL = '         
        DECLARE @Iterator2 varchar(55), @strSQL2 varchar(8000)
        DECLARE xyz2 CURSOR
        FOR
        --Select stuff to iterate over
        SELECT DISTINCT c.name
        FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
             sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN
             sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE t.name = '''+@Iterator+'''

        OPEN xyz2 

        FETCH NEXT FROM xyz2 
        INTO @Iterator2 

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

        --Do stuff
        SET @strSQL2 = ''
        UPDATE '+@Iterator+'
        SET ''+@Iterator2+'' = NULL
        WHERE CHARINDEX(''''-'''',''+@Iterator2+'') <> 0
            ''
        PRINT @strSQL2
            FETCH NEXT FROM xyz2 
            INTO @Iterator2 

        END

        CLOSE xyz2 
        DEALLOCATE xyz2 
        GO
        '       
PRINT (@strSQL)

FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator 

END

CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

This code is incredibly stupid as is, it would literally update every '-' to be NULL across every field for every table in the active DB. Well, in it's current form it will just create the scripts that would do that, if you run it, then run the code it outputs, you'll have all of your update statements.  You can add where criteria to both 'select stuff to iterate over' portions, ie:  WHERE t.name like '%tabletowreck%'  or   in the interior cursor 'WHERE c.name like '%badcolumn%'

Since both cursors 'PRINT' this code is safe to run, I believe it will error if you change both PRINT's to EXEC, but just be wary that this is potentially very dangerous.

Comment: If you literally wanted to "replace all of these values with a NULL in all the tables" you could do that with a nested cursor, but it seems like an exceedingly bad idea.  If it's specific fields across multiple tables then you could specify them and use a single cursor to loop through all tables, I have both versions written out if you'd like...

Comment: Thanks for the reply  Can you please post the code. so that i can test it. Actually what the thing is there are several tables in the  database(approx 50) while loading data some columns are with negative values, empty spaces so should replace them with null across my whole database.